# Sqlite executemany or union select for reduced db writes

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.x

I'm trying to reduce the number of writes to a Sqlite database when it comes to inserting multiple rows into a table.

I've found two methods of doing this so far, using a union select statement or using the executemany command in sqlite3.

Does executemany work via a single write?

For reference, please see the following statement I'm using (union select):

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT "hello" AS field1, 15 AS field2, 1262340000 AS timestamp 
UNION SELECT "byebye", 10, 1262340000 
UNION SELECT "hi", 20, 1262340000 
UNION SELECT "boo", 25, 1262340000
```

UPDATE

I'm aware building an SQL statement via string concatenation is really bad from a security point of view but in this case, the database owner is also the data provider so SQL injection issues can be ignored.

This is for Python 2.7

sqlite3 version 2.6.0

Comment: Unless you are inserting static data, the union method requires string concatenation of the data, which you shouldn't be doing. Also note that recent versions of SQLite can insert multiple rows without doing a select (`INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES (1), (2), (3), ...`)

Comment: I'm using sqlite3 version 2.6.0 where the multiple row insert doesn't appear to be supported..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite flushes data from its page cache to disk when the transaction commits.
So you just need to put all the INSERTs into a single transaction:

```sql
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('hello', 15, 1262340000);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('byebye', 10, 1262340000);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('hi', 20, 1262340000);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('boo', 25, 1262340000);
COMMIT;
```

Python [automatically inserts transactions behind your back](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions), so you can just use a bunch of `execute()`s, or `executemany()`:

```
data = [('hello', 15, 1262340000),
        ('byebye', 10, 1262340000),
        ('hi', 20, 1262340000),
        ('boo', 25, 1262340000)]
con.executemany("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?, ?, ?);", data)
con.commit()
```